# Tapestry: update @for on directLink

Tags: javascript, java, html, tapestry

I have a table generated using `@for` component.
one of the column in table contains a direct link that invokes a method and adds 1 more row to the table source.

Now what I want to do is refresh this table on UI.
it works ok, if I refresh the whole page. But when I am using the updateComponent tag on the directlink. I just see 1 row. My understanding is that my componentid is on a row that is why only one row is getting updated.

Can you suggest, how could I just update the whole table.
I tried putting the @for on say tbody, but that does not work.

Code:

```
<div id="compFeeTableDiv" jwcid="compFeeTableDivTap@Any" style="visibility: hidden">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
        </legend>
        <table height="100%" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2" width="100%" border="0" id="compFeeTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span key="abc" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr jwcid="@For" source="ognl:compFees" value="ognl:compFee" element="tr" index="ognl:loopIndex">
                    <td valign="center" align="center" height="15" class="listlabel2">
                        <span jwcid="@If" condition="true">
                            <div jwcid="@Any">
                                <a href="" jwcid="@DirectLink" name="ognl:'edit_link_'" listener="listener:newCompFee" size="5">
                                    <img src="images/addAction.png" alt="addAction">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Backing Java listener method

```
public void newcompFee(IRequestCycle cycle) {
    compFee newcompFee = compFeeFactory.createDefaultcompFee(null,getAgent().getCompany());
    List<compFee> compFees = getcompFees();
    compFees.add(newcompFee);
    setcompFees(compFees);
    getAgent().getCompany().setcompFeeApplicable(YesNo.Yes);
}
```

I did try the updateComponent attribute on directlink and point it to id of my @for. but that only renders 1 row after refresh.

I am using tapestry 4.1.6.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: `<thead>` not closed

Comment: @Tushar: thanks for pointing that out. fixed it.

Comment: @Tushar. As it turns out.. not closing <thead> was the issue. I closed that. and now I am able to refresh the whoole div using `updateComponent` attribute on the directlink. Thanks. I will post an answer .

Answer (score 0):

So.
The problem was really stupid. it was as @Tusar points out in his comment. it was because `<thead>` was not closed.

What worked for me:

```
<div id="compFeeTableDiv" jwcid="compFeeTableDivTap@Any" style="visibility: hidden">
 <fieldset>
        <legend>
        </legend>
        <table height="100%" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2" width="100%" border="0" id="compFeeTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span key="abc" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr jwcid="@For" source="ognl:compFees" value="ognl:compFee" element="tr" index="ognl:loopIndex">
                    <td valign="center" align="center" height="15" class="listlabel2">
                        <span jwcid="@If" condition="true">
                            <div jwcid="@Any">
                                <a href="" jwcid="@DirectLink" name="ognl:'edit_link_'" listener="listener:newCompFee" size="5" updateComponent="compFeeTableDivTap">
                                    <img src="images/addAction.png" alt="addAction">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

So Basically, i am calling the enclosing div on updateComponent of directlink. Works perfectly.

**UPDATE**
After correcting the  . The whole page was getting refreshed.
The problem here was that there was a typo in `updateComponent`. this should be `updateComponents`.

All works perfectly now